# Search service installation on existing ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, solr

We have ColdFusion 11 installed and working on production Windows Server 2012 R2 server. Search Services and Solr were not initially installed. What would be the steps to add them now?  Is there a simple way to do it on a running system?

Your input and advice are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the installer from https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cf11devtools and install the same.

Comment: Is there something we should be aware of or careful about while running this installer? Can it affect the current production environment? Any known issues? Thank you!

Comment: It will not affect your production system.